# Does this abstract simplicial complex has a name?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, simplicial-complex

Given positive integers $m,n$, let $A_{m,n}$ be an abstract simplicial complex where the vertices are the cells in an $m$-by-$n$ grid, and the faces are sets of cells with at most one cell in each row. I am searching for information on properties of this complex, so first I would like to know: does it have a name?

Note that the complex containing only the sets of cells with at most one cell in each row *and at most one cell in each column* is known as a [chessboard complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard_complex). The facets of the chessboard complex are simplices with $\min(m,n)$ vertices (so they are $\min(m,n)-1$-dimensional). In contrast, the facets of my complex are simplices with $m$ vertices (so they are $m-1$-dimensional). What term describes my complex?

Comment: Most complexes are nameless. You can call it "the row-chessboard complex."

Comment: ... and, fingers crossed, it may one day be called the Segal-Halevi complex $\ddot{\smile}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Frederic Meunier, and he explained to me that the complex I described is simply the [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)) $D_n^{*(2n-1)}$, where:

- $D_n$ is the discrete space with  $n$ points;
- $*$ denotes the join operation;
- $(2n-1)$ denotes the number of times the join is done, that is, the complex is $D_n * D_n * \cdots * D_n$ ($2n-1$ times).

The join is constructed by taking $2n-1$ disjoint copies of $D_n$, and forming all unions of a single simplex from each copy. In each copy, each simplex is either $\emptyset$ or contains a single point. Therefore, if we treat each copy as a row and each point as a cell, we see that each union contains at most one cell from each row.

Note that the chessboard complex is the [deleted join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deleted_join) ${D_n}^{*(2n-1)}_{\Delta}$. A deleted join contains alll unions of *disjoint* simplices from each copy. Therefore, if we treat each copy as a row, and all copies of each element as a column, we see that each union contains at most one cell from each row and at most one cell from each column.